# call a function after another function is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call another function after load() is completed. I first tried to check with alert(), however, I see the alert before load() is done. I am able to successfully load content in load() function. However, alert() is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    load();
    $.when(load()).done(function(){
        alert((document.getElementById('item').innerHTML));
    });        

    function load()
    { 
        $("#item").load("/somepage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr){
              if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "error: ";
                $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
              }
        });                         
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `load()` to return a promise, and then you pass this promise to `$.when`.

`.load()` doesn't return a promise, it returns the jQuery collection that it was called on (for chaining purposes). You can rewrite `load()` using `$.get()` instead, which returns a `jQXHR`, which implements `Deferred` (that's jQuery's promise class).

```
var p = load();
$.when(p).done(function() {
    alert($("#item").html());
});

function load() {
    return $.get("/somepage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr){
        $("#item").html(response);
        if ( status == "error" ) {
            var msg = "error: ";
            $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
        }
    });
}
```

You don't actually need to use `$.when`, you can just write:

```
p.done(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Looks like you're right. I was thinking it was like the other AJAX shorthand functions.

Comment: thnks a lot Barmar it worked now. In somepage.aspx, i have used $.ajax to call web service and returned the data which i appended in that page. Now when i use load() to upload that data, even though i can see the data content, i can't get any elements. Is there solution for that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, it would be best if you posted the details in a new question.

Comment: But first read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: using the method shown earlier, how can i retrieve only content of .aspx page. Say, div content with id #p. thnks.

Comment: You can use `$("#item").load("/somepage.aspx #p", function(response, status, xhr) { ... });`

Comment: ya i used that earlier but didn't load anything because i would have to trigger the javascript functions inside the page to load that content. I guess i would load the whole page and parse the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback functions and update your code to following

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    load(function(){
        alert((document.getElementById('item').innerHTML));
    });

    function load(callback)
    { 
        $("#item").load("/somepage.aspx", function (response, status, xhr){
              if ( status == "error" ) {
                var msg = "error: ";
                $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
              }
              if(callback) {
                   callback();
              }
        });                         
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new [Promises](http://caniuse.com/#search=Promise) API which is already implemented in most major browsers.

```
var jsonPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // do a thing, possibly async, then…

    if ( /* everything turned out fine */ ) {
        resolve("Stuff worked!");
    } 
    else {
        reject(Error("It broke"));
   }
});

jsonPromise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```